# Ajax returned form not submitting

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a webpage on which html contents are fetched using ajax calls, the ajax call also returned form element.

After the form is added to the page using ajax, when i try to submit the form its not workign and give me error that form elements are undefined.

Code is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url/" + $("#search_id").val(),
    async: false, 
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error!!");
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        $("#parent-element").html("");
        $("#parent-element").append(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
});
//Delegate click event
$('body').delegate('div#footer #submit1','click', function() {
      var form_element=document.getElementById('search_form');
      verifyChecked(form_element);
});

function verifyChecked (form_obj) {
         var formname = form_obj.name;
         var orig_query = document[formname].query.value;
         if (orig_query == "") {
            return false;
         };
         form_obj.submit();
         return false;
     }
```

The above code snippet makes ajax call and appends the html contents which had the form element which looks like this

```
<form id="search_form">
<input type="hidden" value="SOMETHING" name="search">
<input id="query_data" type="text" value="test" name="query">
</form>
```

Now, when i click the submit button, i get error that: 
TypeError: document[formname].query is undefined

Please help in getting it corrected.

---

NOTE: The problem is the form elements are not binded to the form. The input elements are shown in HTML but i think are not there in DOM. SO thats why my form submission does not have the input elements.

SO the problem is i want to get the input elements binded to form, how can i do this? Do i need to reload DOM and how i do it?.

This is what i exactly trying to do: [JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/akawax/1/edit)

I have found the solution now, earlier my form was like this:

```
<form name="search" id='search_form' action="https://mysearch/search?" onSubmit="return verifyChecked(this);">
<tr>
 <td id="input_p" width="100%">
  <input type="hidden" value="SOMETHING" name="search">
  <input id="query_data" type="text" value="test" name="query">
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="image" src="graphics/search.gif" id="submit1" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </form>
```

Now i have moved my form tag to inside the same td as input tags:

```
 <tr>
 <td id="input_p" width="100%">
 <form name="search" id='search_form' action="https://mysearch/search?" onSubmit="return verifyChecked(this);">
  <input type="hidden" value="SOMETHING" name="search">
  <input id="query_data" type="text" value="test" name="query">
 </form>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="image" src="graphics/search.gif" id="submit1" />
 </td>
 </tr>
```

and bingo.. it started working.
I don't have explanation why its working. As i have the same form and DOM structure on my page above which works perfectly, but for the form tag returned by ajax call it doesnot work. Any explanations will be helpful in understanding why its working.

Comment: `document[formname].query` - show code where this string is. And how it is called.

Comment: sorry, that's my perl code, will edit it

Comment: search_form is the id for my form

Comment: Plz see my edit i have posted the verifyChecked code

Comment: BTW: Where's your submit button? Based on your HTML code excerpt there seems to be no Submit button in this particular form.

Comment: its just code snippet have not shown it, but yes it is there :)

Comment: Must be a reason for down vote.. clarify you guys if you can ...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
var orig_query = document[formname].query.value;
```

to:

```
var orig_query = $('#query_data').val();
```

and see if that works. If it does then see more details below.

If you are already using jQuery then use it to a full extent.

```
$('body').delegate('#submit1','click', function() {
    var $form_element = $('#search_form');
    verifyChecked($form_element);
});

function verifyChecked ($form) {
    var orig_query = $('#query_data').val();
    if (orig_query != "") {
        $form.submit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have problems with form validation then consider using some library that would simplify that task for you, like the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) or [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/).

Comment: will check it, but would like to say, that i don't want to change verifyChecked as its being used at different places too

Comment: well in dat case i guess u can call another function

Comment: @kailash19 if your verifyChecked is incorrect and you don't want to change it then you're out of luck.

Comment: @rsp: I have other forms too on page and verifyChecked works for other forms, so i dont think its incorrect

Comment: error: document.getElementById("query_data") is null

Comment: @kailash19 - if document.getElementById("query_data") is null then you **don't** have this element that you said you have: `<input id="query_data" type="text" value="test" name="query">`. If you don't include the actual code in your question then no one will be able to guess how it looks like.

Comment: @rsp - I have checked my html in firebug, its there, how can i assure you :)

Comment: @kailash19 - you can assure me (and other people who try to help you here) by posting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) example. Certainly you won't assure me that you have an element with id "query_data" in the DOM and yet document.getElementById("query_data") is null. I believe that the code that you posted in your question is not exactly what happens on your page and in that case everyone who tries to help may be wasting time.

Comment: @rsp, That's the right thing you did, + 1.

Comment: I was not able reproduce the problem fiddle, but its happening on my page. Please see my recent edit to question.

Comment: @kailash19 if you want anyone to help you then: **1)** show the **original** html where you have the element with `id="search_id"`. **2)** explain **where** do you call your AJAX (in some Search button click handler? in a text field change handler? show it.) **3)** show the **actual** data that is returned by the AJAX call adding `alert(data)` or `console.dir(data)` to your success callback. **4)** **Don't write** *"Code is something like this"* but write instead **"Code is exactly this"** and **5)** At least **try** posting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) code.

Comment: @rsp: please check my update, i have also posted jsbin code. I have got it working now, but am not able to understand why its working.

Answer (score 1):

Your form

```
<form id="search_form">...</form> <!-- No name -->
```

In your function you have used `var formname = form_obj.name;` but your form has no name but `id` so this `var orig_query = document[formname].query.value;` won't work.

Try this

```
function verifyChecked (form_obj) {
     var formId = form_obj.id;
     var orig_query = document.getElementById(formId).query.value;
     if (orig_query == "") {
        return false;
     }
     form_obj.submit();
     return false;
 }
```

**Update:**
You are using `jQuery` so you can also use following

```
$(document).on('click', 'div#footer #submit1', function(){ // delegate is fine too
    verifyChecked($('#search_form')[0]);
});
```

and your function

```
function verifyChecked (form_obj) {
    var orig_query = $('#query_data', form_obj).val();
    if (orig_query == "") {
        return false;
     }
     form_obj.submit();
}
```

Comment: It'll definitely work, thanks.

Comment: ok, the issue now i have is orig_query value is always blank, even though i am having its value set.

Comment: [This is working](http://jsbin.com/owohoq/1/edit).

Comment: my form is fetched by ajax call, its not present when page is loaded.. do it has something to do with it??

Comment: After appended dynamically, [It's working here](http://jsbin.com/owohoq/3/edit).

Comment: no ajax call made, the form is added when document is loaded. I have my form returned as html by a ajax call.

Comment: It doesn' matter whether i've made an ajax call or not but the matter is i've inserted the form and also button by javascript, it wasn't present in the dom.

Comment: you may be right, but its not working for me :(, i think ajax has something to do with.

Comment: @kailash19 - post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) example that **doesn't work**. Sheikh Heera took the time to write examples that **work** and they are consistent with all of the details of your question (+1 for that). I have also answered how to fix your code **if it looked like you say it does**. I think that you misrepresent what is actually happening so do us and yourself a favor and take some time to post some actual examples that act as you say it does or otherwise no one will be able to help you and we are just wasting our time here.

Comment: Thanks Sheikh for your time and efforts, please check my edit for the solution i got, i still not sure why its working. I appreciate your efforts. :). The problem was with HTML i think but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function verifyChecked (form_obj) {

     var orig_query = document.getElementById('query_data').value;
     if (orig_query == "") {
        return false;
     };
     form_obj.submit();
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Error: document.getElementById("query_data") is null :(